# How to handle JavaScript synchronously

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I want to call a function A that returns an int.
function A calls function B, which changes some values needed by function A to correctly proceed.
Something like this:

```
global variable value;

function A(){
   // do some stuff
   B();
   //do some stuff
   return value;
}

function B(){
   //does some stuff that times time
   //changes value
}
```

My problem is that function A returns before function B finishes.
I have looked at callbacks but that doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.
Is there a practical way to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "some stuff" doesn't tell us much about what's happening.  Do you have a more concrete example?  If you're performing an asynchronous operation then you'd either need to `await` it or use a callback.

Comment: what are your "//do some stuff"s? maybe you're doin' something asynchronous and you need to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: If A is returning before B is finished processing, that means that something is running asynchronously. The way to fix this is to use `await [promise]`